# How to configure GCP pub/sub dead letter with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to set up a pretty routine Cloud Store -> Pub/Sub -> Cloud Run process using Terraform.

```
// Service Account 
resource "google_service_account" "example_sa" {
  account_id   = "example-sa"
  display_name = "Cloud Run Pub/Sub Invoker"
}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project = "example"
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  members = ["serviceAccount:${google_service_account.example_sa.email}"]
}

// Buckets
resource "google_storage_bucket" "example_drop_bucket" {
  name          = "example-drop"
  location      = "EU"
  force_destroy = true
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}

// Cloud Storage Topics
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "example_drop_topic" {
  name = "example-drop"
}
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "example_drop_topic_binding" {
  topic   = google_pubsub_topic.example_drop_topic.id
  role    = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  members = ["serviceAccount:${google_service_account.example_sa.email}"]
}
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "example_parse_fail" {
  name = "example-parse-fail"
}
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "example_parse_fail_binding" {
  topic   = google_pubsub_topic.example_parse_fail.id
  role    = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  members = ["serviceAccount:${google_service_account.example_sa.email}"]
}

// Cloud Storage Notification
resource "google_storage_notification" "notification" {
  bucket         = google_storage_bucket.example_drop_bucket.name
  payload_format = "JSON_API_V1"
  topic          = google_pubsub_topic.example_drop_topic.id
  event_types    = ["OBJECT_FINALIZE", "OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE"]
}

// Set up the parser job
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "example_parser" {
  //...
}
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_binding" "binding" {
  //...
}

// Subscribe
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "example_drop_bucket_subscription" {
  name  = "example-drop"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.example_drop_topic.name

  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic     = google_pubsub_topic.example_parse_fail.id
    max_delivery_attempts = 10
  }
}
```

However, when I visit the GCP console page for the subscription, I see:
[image: GCP Console Subscription]

How do I get the "Cloud Pub/Sub Service Account" and assign the publisher role? Or does this matter?

Answer (score 2):

Try to give theses roles to this service account : service-{PROJECT-NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code (replace `{PROJECT_NUMBER}` before running) that get's the job done

```
# example.tf

# Pub/Sub automatically creates a service account for you with the format
# service-{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com
# https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#properties_of_a_push_subscription
variable "pubsub_service_account_email" {
  type    = string
  default = "service-{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "dead_letter_topic" {
  name = "dead_letter_topic"
}

# Create a subscription so that we don't lose messages published to dead letter topic
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "deadletter_topic_sub" {
  name  = "deadletter_topic_sub"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_topic.name
}

# Allow pubsub to publish to dead letter topic
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_member" "pubsub_sa_publish_deadletter_topic" {
  topic  = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_topic.name
  role   = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  member = "serviceAccount:${var.pubsub_service_account_email}"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "input_topic" {
  name = "input_topic"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "input_topic_sub" {
  name  = "input_topic_sub"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.input_topic.name
  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic     = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_topic.id
    max_delivery_attempts = 5
  }
}

# Allow pubsub to pull from input subscription
resource "google_pubsub_subscription_iam_member" "pubsub_sa_pull_input_topic_sub" {
  subscription = google_pubsub_subscription.input_topic_sub.name
  role         = "roles/pubsub.subscriber"
  member       = "serviceAccount:${var.pubsub_service_account_email}"
}
```

[image: google cloud console screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

GCP Support replied on my query of custom service account:
Currently, we only support the default service account for Pub/Sub. So, you would not be able to use a custom account for now.

There is an active feature request asking for the custom accounts to be allowed -
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274924909